# Sequelizejs not giving clean data

Tags: express, sequelize.js

When I query my database through sequelize.js using the following query:

```
            models.User.findAll({
              attributes: ['name', 'company_id'],
              where: {
                id: 6
              }
            }).then( function( data ) {
              console.log( data );
            });
```

I get :

```
            [ { dataValues: { name: 'John', company_id: 221 },
                _previousDataValues: { name: 'John', company_id: 221 },
                _changed: {},
                '$modelOptions': 
                 { timestamps: true,
                   instanceMethods: {},
                   classMethods: {},
                   validate: {},
                   freezeTableName: false,
                   underscored: false,
                   underscoredAll: false,
                   paranoid: false,
                   whereCollection: [Object],
                   schema: null,
                   schemaDelimiter: '',
                   defaultScope: null,
                   scopes: [],
                   hooks: {},
                   indexes: [],
                   name: [Object],
                   tableName: 'users',
                   createdAt: 'created',
                   updatedAt: 'modified',
                   omitNull: false,
                   sequelize: [Object],
                   uniqueKeys: {},
                   hasPrimaryKeys: true },
                '$options': { isNewRecord: false, raw: true, attributes: [Object] },
                hasPrimaryKeys: true,
                __eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
                isNewRecord: false } ]
```

How do I configure sequelize to give me clean data,i.e., only data rows and nothing else.

Comment: What is your end goal with this?  You can actually do `var userName = data[0].name` even though console.log doesn't show that key/value.

Comment: No.I can't.I have to go like var userName = `data[0]['dataValues']['name']` . `data[0].name` is undefined.